# Prestashop: coupon value - the total value of the contract in "blockuserinfo"

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop

Is it possible to subtract these two values, so that the value changes dynamically depending on the order sum?

```
<span id="cart_blockuserinfo">
     {displayPrice price=$cart->getordertotal(false)}
</span>
<span>
    <p>{foreach $displayVouchers as $voucher} {$voucher.reduction_amount} {/foreach}</p>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably something like this should work:

```
<span id="cart_blockuserinfo">
     {displayPrice price=$cart->getordertotal(false)}
</span>
<span>
    <p>{foreach $displayVouchers as $voucher} {$voucher.reduction_amount} ({displayPrice price=$cart->getordertotal(false) - $voucher.reduction_amount}) {/foreach}</p>
</span>
```

Comment: It works great, but it returns a negative result. Any suggestions how fix this?

Comment: I don't know what are exactly those 2 variables. `$cart->getordertotal(false)` - I assume this is total cost of all products in your cart. But what are `$displayVouchers` and how `reduction_amount` is defined - is it in `%` or in value for example `3` (currency) ?

Comment: $displayVoucher is value from DB, in this case $cart->getordertotal(false) < $displayVouchers

Comment: Ok, but I don't know how it's calculated. You can simple change the order to `price=$voucher.reduction_amount - $cart->getordertotal(false)` but I don't know if it will bring desired values

Comment: i po naszemu, wielkie dzięki, dopiero teraz zobaczyłe, że pisze rodak ;). Fajnie, że są fachowcy, którym chce sie pomagać laikom :)